# Reading 500 million records from cassandra using spark performance issue

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

Guys I am using below code to read entire table from cacssandra using spark

```
val ds = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(Map( "table" -> "part", "keyspace" -> 
      "electronic_parts","spark.cassandra.input.fetch.split.size.in.mbs" -> "500")).load()
```

I tried this split size setting etc but didnt give me much difference. Its almost taking around couple of hours to read it and write as parquet format. Is there a way to get it done maybe in half hr. I am doing any processing as of now and almost using an 49 node cluster. If I do some processing its taking more time.

Comment: What is your total memory and what is the executor and Cores you are using

Comment: 56.0 GB Memory, 8 Cores, 2 DBU
50node cluster

Comment: 56g each node. Try to increase the number of executors to  40 and core to 4. See how the performance.